# Class member function pointers in C++

Tags: c++

I want to call a member function of another class on an object, but I cant seem to figure out how this works. As example code on how it should work:

```
Class A {
  void somefunction(int x);
}

Class B : A {
  void someotherfunction(int x);
}

Class C {
  void x() {
      callY(&ofthefunction); 
}   //here you call the function, you dont have an object yet,    and you don't know the argument yet, this will be found in function callY

  void Y(*thefunction) {
       find int x;
       if(something)
             A a = find a;
             a->thefunction(x);
       else 
             B b = find b;
             b->thefunction(x);
}
}
```

I hope this makes sence, It is also possible to split this in 2 methods, Y1 and Y2, but seeing as 90% of the code is the same (finding things in a XML file), only the object and argument where to save it is different, i'd like to do this

Comment: You hope that makes sense? No it doesn't. Post atleast compilable Code. What should we assume about your knowledge of C++ if your code doesn't even compile, with so many syntax errors and all?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something known as a virtual function. By the way, your syntax is hideous, it's `class` not `Class`, you need braces for your conditionals, and a judicious application of `public`, some extra semicolons, etc. It would be appreciated if you  would go near a compiler before coming here, y'know.

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void somefunction(int x);
};

class B : public A {
public:
  virtual void somefunction(int x);
};

void func(A& a) {
    int x = 0;
    // Do something to find x
    a.somefunction(x); 
    // calls A::somefunction if this refers to an A
    // or B::somefunction if it's a B
}
int main() {
    A a;
    func(a); // calls A::somefunction
    B b;
    func(b); // calls B::somefunction
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I was trying to write pseudocode, not the actual C++ code? Maybe I am trying to make it too complicated, the thing is I only have C lessons at school, not C++,so I'm tring to do it in a C way probably.
It will still not solve my problem seeying as class A in your example has 2 practicly identical functions, called truefunction and falsefunction, thats where the problem arises, if i could give a pointer to the function instead of actually specifying a name in func(A& a) it would be solved.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do *can* be done, although I woudn't solve it this way:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual int doit(int x) { return x+1; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    int doit2(int x) { return x*3; }
    int doit(int x) { return x*2; }
};

int foo(int (A::*func)(int), int x, bool usea) {
    if (usea) {
        A a;
        return (a.*func)(x);
    } else {
        B b;
        return (b.*func)(x);
    }
}

int main() {
    int (A::*bla)(int) = &A::doit;
    foo(bla, 3, true);
    foo(bla, 3, false);

}
```

However, for this to work, the following has to be satisfied:

1. You must use function pointers of the base class (e.g. `int (A::*bla)(int)`), otherwise you won't be able to call it on that base class (e.g. `int (B::*bla)(int)` can only be used on `B` instances, not on `A` instances, even if the method is already defined in `A`).
2. The methods must have the same names as in the base class
3. To use overriding (e.g. different impl in derived class), you have to use `virtual` functions.

But I would rather rethink your design...

Comment: Nice clean code that works. Though I have not tried coding it, C++ templates seem to be the right approach to me.

Comment: About the rethink of my design: It would be possible to just make it so that i have an if else if and else, because I only have 3 member functions as options(but with different names, sadly, seeing as class A has 1 name, and class B has 2 other names but with similar results)! But I was just curious if it could be done the way I am asking, seeing as I come from C coding, where this would have been easy

Answer (score 0):

No, that won't work at all. A pointer to a member of A will always point to that function, even when it's called on B because B inherits from A.

You need to use virtual functions. I see DeadMG has beaten me to it.